# Disable Foreign Key Constraints with INSERT and UPDATE Statements due to foreign key constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting Foreign key constraint while inserting the data into database as there is null data in key column. So if I disable foreign key by making **Enforce Foreign Key Constraint** to **No**, to insert that one row of data and enable it again for future transactions will it be a problem for the existing data?

Comment: just pass 0 in place of null using isnull(column,0). By this you dont have to enforce any thing

Comment: Can you be clear on where you're trying to insert this `null` value? Is the column part of a *foreign key reference* or an actual (primary/unique) key column? If the latter, foreign keys are irrelevant. If the former, *most* database system will, I believe, already not enforce that foreign key constraint. But there could be product specific settings that are relevant.

Comment: You could use deferrable foreign keys

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever it's sql-server

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything special to accommodate `NULL`s in SQL Server foreign keys. If any of the referencing columns contain `NULL` then the foreign key constraint isn't checked and isn't violated:

```
create table T1 (
    ID int not null,
    constraint PK_T1 PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
go
create table T2 (
    ID int not null,
    T1ID int null,
    constraint PK_T2 PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    constraint FK_T2_T1 FOREIGN KEY (T1ID)
        references T1(ID)
)
go
insert into T1(ID) values (1),(2)
go
insert into T2(ID,T1ID) values (1,1), (2,null)
go
```

This runs without any errors.

In regard to disabling foreign keys, you should generally avoid doing this, especially if the goal is to insert data that violates the key. Even though you can re-enable the key in such a way that it only validates new data, the key will never be *trusted* (and rightfully so).

As such, the query optimizer will not be able to make use of the foreign key constraint to obtain optimal query plans.